# Multiple repositories and Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, web

I have two git repositories (frontend and backend). Say, i need to push frontend to heroku and **don't** touch backend. Simple static files update, right? Should be easy. But it's not. I have to manually put my static files from frontend into backend repository and push backend to heroku. Then wait for build, env install etc. All this just to upload some files. Is there another way? Maybe some manipulations with git submodule or something like that?

Comment: Have you manage to solve it?

Comment: @chenop, yep. I've posted an anser. Hope it's useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i've learned: The right way to do this is to have **multiple heroku apps**. It's kind of heroku's pattern. Build an app for each of your microservices. So e.g. you will have frontend app at `web.yourdomain.com`, auth microservice at `auth.yourdomain.com`, long-polling server at `updates.yourdomain.com` etc. Or you can redirect all requests from clients via `api.yourdomain.com`.

Point is, you have multiple repositories for multiple apps. That seems to be it.

Comment: That's a shame. And you have to pay for each separately too, rather than sharing resources.